# Assigning Optional String to UILabel in UITableView ends in unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, null, amazon-dynamodb

I have a `UITableView` in my Swift-written iOS app. This `UITableView` has 2 classes: `TableViewController`, to control the table, and `TableViewCell`, to control the cells of the `UITableView`.

On `HomeViewController` I load 2 things from DynamoDB, array of items from a table named `items`, and an `Int` variable with the number of items in the array named `numberOfItems`. I know those values aren't nil, since I'm printing them to the console to check it, and I get valid results printed in the console.

On `tableView(numberOfRowsInSection:)` method I have this code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("numberOfRowsInSection", HomeViewController.GlobalVars.numberOfItems)
    return HomeViewController.GlobalVars.numberOfItems
}
```

The print function in the method returns the exact number of items there should be to the console.

on `tableView(cellForRowAt:)` method I have this code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "TableViewCell"
    self.tableView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of TableViewCell.")
    }

    print("indexPath.row", indexPath.row)
    let item: Item = HomeViewController.GlobalVars.items[indexPath.row]
    let name: String = item.name!
    cell.itemNameLabel.text? = name

    return cell
}
```

Now, some of the things that aren't understood in the code:
1) `Item` is my DynamoDB Object Mapper.
2)`itemNameLabel` is a `UILabel` in `TableViewCell` that I connected using `Ctrl + Drag` from the storyboard to `TableViewCell` file.
3) I'm printing the value of `indexPath.row` because I previously got a fatal error about `Index out of range`, so I've added this print function to check if the index is inside the range (It is).
4) To check if the `name` String is valid, I've added this line to check:

```
print("name", name)
```

And I got the name of the item without any errors printed on the console.

The current problem is that whenever I run this code, I get this error log on the console:

```
numberOfRowsInSection 3
numberOfRowsInSection 3
numberOfRowsInSection 3
numberOfRowsInSection 3
indexPath.row 0
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

As you can see, for some reason it prints the `numberOfRowsInSection` 4 times, and sometimes it prints 3 times.

It runs until the line where I set the text of the `UILabel` to be the variable, but then I get the fatal error message. The error is shown on the line where I set the text, with this error message:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

The String itself is probably valid because when I'm printing the `name` variable I get the value I should get.

What can I do to fix this and show the value on the `UILabel` in the `UITableView`?

**EDIT #1**:
The variables in the DynamoDB Object Mapper are optionals:

```
import UIKit
import AWSDynamoDB

class Item: AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling {

    var id: String?
    var category: String?
    var name: String?

    class func dynamoDBTableName() -> String {
        return "Items"
    }

    class func hashKeyAttribute() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `?` in `cell.itemNameLabel.text?`?

Comment: Use Optional chaning it will help "(  let name: String =  item.name ??  ""  )"

Comment: @Losiowaty I get the same error on the same line

Comment: @phanisai I still get the same error on the same line

Comment: Look at the edit I made to the question

Comment: @IdoNaveh have you add number of section delegate?

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya Yes. I need only one section, so in the sections method I wrote `return 1`

Comment: @IdoNaveh add this line into viewDidload instead of tableview delegate "self.tableView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)"

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya It is still not working

Comment: @IdoNaveh follow this link https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-register-a-cell-for-uitableviewcell-reuse

Comment: @Ido Naveh, Please check object "item" is nil or not if u not able decide make like line like this "( let name: String = item?.name ?? "" )"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possibilities.**

There might be two possibilities of this Crash.

As you have tried `if let` as well as tried by removing force unwrap then their is a single chance that might be your Label outlet is unconnected with you storyboard instance. May be your Label is nil.
Please check the Label connection if its been removed for some reason then please create that outlet again.
To test it please remove the line of code which assign name to label.
Simply assign an empty string to it and if it still crash then for sure your Label is nil.

Answer (score 3):

## Explanation:

An optional is capable of holding a value or a nil.

Don't force unwrap an optional unless you are sure it contains a non-nil value.

## Solution:

```
let name: String = item.name
cell.itemNameLabel.text = name
```

- `cell.itemNameLabel.text` is an optional too, so you don't have to unwrap `item.name`.
- It would be best if you learn Swift Optionals.

## Reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Comment: I still get the same error for the same line... Look at the edit I made

Comment: Is item.name declared as implicit optional ? (example: `var name : String!`) ?

Comment: No, it is declared as `var name: String?`

Comment: I have just tried to change it to implicit optional (using `!`) but I still get the same error

Comment: Your edited code still contains `!` No don't use implicit optionals

Comment: I added just the DynamoDB Object Mapper code, I didn't edit the whole code in question, but currently my code is without `!`. What do you suggest to do?

Comment: Paste the exact line that throws an error and paste the exact error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144052/discussion-between-user1046037-and-ido-naveh).

Answer (score 0):

Use guard or if let to avoid such crashes.
As your last three lines in `cellForRowAt` method are

```
let name: String = item.name!
cell.itemNameLabel.text? = name
return cell
```

Change the above code into this.

```
if let name = item.name {
    //If you get inside this if block it means your name variable is not nil.
    cell.itemNameLabel.text = name
}else {
    //If you are in else block it means your name variable is nil.
    //Assign Empty string to label.
    cell.itemNameLabel.text = ""
}
return cell
```

Thats how you will get rid of such crashes.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but I still get the fatal error, on the line from the `if` block (`cell.itemNameLabel.text = name`)

Comment: Can you send you crash log screenshot ?

Comment: Do you mean to the error I get on the console? If so, then I posted it on the question